# Insert a copy of a row in a table and checking for duplicates

Tags: sql, ssms, cc

I am looking to copy 4 existing rows in a database and need to change the value of one of the columns in the new rows. I need to do this and also make sure that no duplicates are created. What I have so far is

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT 141, col2, col3,
FROM table
WHERE col1 = 99 AND NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 = 141, col2, col3)
```

However, when I try run this, I have a syntax error at the comma in my (SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 = 141, col2, col3) row.

Can anyone help?

EDIT: I have 4 rows with the following values in my database

| col1 | col 2 | col 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | 1 | Enabled |
| 99 | 3 | A |
| 99 | 4 | B |
| 99 | 5 | C |

and I want to create the following rows, but check for duplicates first

| col1 | col 2 | col 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 141 | 1 | Enabled |
| 141 | 3 | A |
| 141 | 4 | B |
| 141 | 5 | C |

Comment: Commas are not accepted in `WHERE`.  And your intention rather unclear.  You specify that you want to copy *four* values, but the statement only has three columns.  Overall, I can't make sense out of the question.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question so I hope this is clearer to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the EXCEPT keyword in your select (or MINUS if you use Oracle):

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT 141, col2, col3,
FROM table
WHERE col1 = 99
EXCEPT
SELECT 141, col2, col3,
FROM table
WHERE col1 = 141;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just removing col2 and col3 should solve the problem.

```
  INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3)
    SELECT 141, col2, col3
FROM table_name t1
WHERE col1 = 99 AND NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM table_name t2 WHERE t2.col1 = 141 and t1.col2=t2.col2 and t1.col3=t2.col3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried this, but if I already have an existing row in my table with the value of 141, it doesn't add the other 3 it needs to copy

Comment: @smose I have changed my answer to adopt this situation. It will now only insert the rows which don't have same col2 and col3 for 141 in col1.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem now with the following:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT 141, col2, col3,
FROM table t
WHERE col1 = 99 AND NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM table nt
WHERE nt.col1 = 141 AND nt.col2 = t.col2 AND nt.col3 = t.col3)
```